# Databricks: access storage account behind specific vnet

Tags: databricks, azure-storage-account

I would like to have some advice on the databricks to access blob storage account which is only allow access from specific subnet. Thanks
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need vnet deploy your databricks instance https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject.html

This will allow you to act as any other machine connected to the vnet.

Comment: there is already vnet during the creation of the databricks. But I failed at enabling the service endpoint.

Comment: Yes that’s the default vnet. But you need a vnet attached to your network that can access the storage account. Read the link I posted.

Comment: yes. I tried. but still failed. I create another specific subnet for databricks. 
I can access the blob from databricks, however , it seems failed at polybase part.

Comment: still can't . any one has the idea